# Best way to modify site to allow anonymous comments

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Now I have one table "comments" with 'user_id' column as foreign key. This column have a constraint - `ON UPDATE CASCADE, ON DELETE CASCADE`.

First (bad) way is to remove constraints for 'user_id' column. In that case we loosing connection with 'users' table, but all code stay same.

Second (also not good) way is to create one more table 'anonymous_comments'. New model, new observers, new chapter in admin panel, need to modify code in many places... many work & doubles.

Any better ideas?

Comment: So what's wrong with querying the users table with a JOIN on comments load?

Comment: comments loading isn't problem. Comments managing - that's a problem.

Comment: Foreign Key columns allow you to insert null values. Why not just insert null for the user_id column for anonymous comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want (or can't for some reason) to do any DB and code modifications, you could create a dummy user 'anonymous' and use it's `user_id` for anonymous comments.

Comment: in that case we loosing all 'anonymous' comments if removing that user (by mistake, for example).

Comment: @SlowSuperman dude, you can remove all DBs by mistake. Just add check in a user deletion method like `if ($user->id = 78) { return false; }`

Comment: Good idea. Is there same method for MySQL to prevent deleting row with id '0', for example?

Comment: @SlowSuperman I'm not sure about that, sorry. I'd just add some small check in the existing code.